# find doesnt find button which is clearly in dom when testing ember view

Tags: javascript, testing, ember.js, qunit

Hey I have following problem with qunit acceptance test:

```
test('', assert => {
  selectSearch('.address-lookup', '359 Paterson Road');
  fillIn('input.mailing-address-city', 'Arlington');
  fillIn('input.mailing-address-postal-code', '76002');


  andThen(() => {
   const discoverDriverBtn = find('.discover-driver-button')
   click(discoverDriverBtn);
  });
})
```

button `.discover-driver-button` is in template in `if` statement whe all inputs are filled

I see this button in qunit preview when running test and after stopping it I can find it in console

yet test is failing with message:

```
Error: Element [object Object] not found.
```

when I deleted `if` from view and displayed button all time the test passed

I think it might be connected somehow with run loop

Comment: so my answer did not help?

Answer (score 0):

You indicated button `.discover-driver-button` in template is visible only `if` all inputs are filled. However; the test code snippet you provided does not perform a fill with `ember-power-select`. Please have a look at the [documentation](http://www.ember-power-select.com/docs/test-helpers). `selectSearch` helper only makes a search with the select field; whereas `selectChoose` does in fact makes the actual selection. If you use `selectChoose` in place of `selectSearch` (or after `selectSearch`) your test will most likely pass.